# INSERT INTO wont work

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-insert

I am getting no errors on this but the sql table wont get any data...

```
<?php 

error_reporting(E_ALL);

ini_set('display_errors', '1');

header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","123456","bikeshop");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
session_start();
$name=$_SESSION['username'];
$totalprice = $_POST['totalprice2'];
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$adress = $_POST['adress'];
$mobilephone = $_POST['mobilephone'];
$postalcode = $_POST['postalcode'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$homephone = $_POST['homephone'];
$deliveryinfo = $_POST['deliveryinfo'];
$status = 'pending';

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO orderbank (firstname, lastname, email, adress, mobilephone, postalcode, city, homephone, deliveryinfo, cost, status) VALUES  ('$firstname','$lastname','$email','$adress',''$mobilephone','$postalcode',city,'$homephone','$deliveryinfo','$totalprice','$status')");

?>
```

Comment: You aren't checking for errors...

Comment: You have `,city,` without quotes or the sigil. That will give you an error for sure. Also, please don't use interpolated strings, or unsanitized user input. This is awful.

Comment: @user0000000: How exactly would that help, if I may ask?

Comment: @AmalMurali: it will give a definite error as opposed to a potential one.

Comment: Complete `if` bracks before completing `?>`

Comment: @siride Yes, but I still don't see how that would "*help*" :P

Comment: No errors? I'm sure your `.ini` file has display_errors set to `0`. Plus, with what's already been mentioned, you have an extra quote in `''$mobilephone'`

Comment: removed the quotes .dosent work :/

Comment: @user0000000: the variables are inside a string. The quotes you are talking about are relevant for SQL, where they are probably required.

Comment: This one's a real can 'o worms.

Comment: @user0000000 You need to quote string literals in the `VALUES()` list. Double-quotes also work but depending on the MySQL server's `sql_mode`, that could change.

Comment: this query is free for any errors via unescaped data.

Answer (score 4):

Look at your `VALUES` line in the query:

```
VALUES ('$firstname','$lastname','$email','$adress',''$mobilephone','$postalcode',city,'$homephone','$deliveryinfo','$totalprice','$status')
```

Shouldn’t `,city,` be `,'$city',`? And why are there two  single quotes `'` in front of `$mobilephone`

Try changing that to this:

```
VALUES ('$firstname','$lastname','$email','$adress','$mobilephone','$postalcode','$city','$homephone','$deliveryinfo','$totalprice','$status')
```

That said, you are also not doing any error catching for the query. Lots of issues here.

That said, here is a refactoring of your code to make this all a bit cleaner & more stable. Note the use of [`mysqli_error`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to report errors on the query as well as [`mysqli_connect_error`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php) for the connection. Also using an array of `$_POST` values to allow for easier processing of the `$_POST` values. Which also allows for some basic validation of the input with `isset()` and `!empty()`. Also using [`mysqli_stmt_bind_param`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to set variables in the query.  And finally using [`mysqli_free_result`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php) & [`mysqli_close`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php) to cleanly get free memory & close the connection after everything is said & done.

```
// Sundry items set by the original poster in the original code.
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
session_start();

// Credentials.
$host = "127.0.0.1";
$user = "root";
$password = "123456";
$database = "bikeshop";

// Connecting, selecting database
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());

// Set a '$_POST' array and roll through each value.
$post_array = array('totalprice2', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'adress', 'mobilephone', 'postalcode', 'city', 'homephone', 'deliveryinfo');
foreach ($post_array as $post_key => $post_value) {
  $$post_value = isset($_POST[$post_value]) && !empty($_POST[$post_value]) ? $_POST[$post_value] : null;
}

// Set the other variables.
$name = $_SESSION['username'];
$status = 'pending';

// Set the query.
$query = "INSERT INTO `orderbank` (`firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `adress`, `mobilephone`, `postalcode`, `city`, `homephone`, `deliveryinfo`, `cost`, `status`)"
       . " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
       ;

// Bind the params.
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($insertsql, 'sssssssssss', $firstname, $lastname, $email, $adress, $mobilephone, $postalcode, $city, $homephone, $deliveryinfo, $totalprice2, $status);

// Run the query.
$result = mysqli_query($con, $insertsql) or die(mysqli_error());

// Free the result set.
mysqli_free_result($result);

// Close the connection.
mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: near mobile `,''$mobilephone'` is also extra single quote

Comment: Two points. 1. `or die(mysqli_connect_errno());` will only output anything if there are any connection errors. You need `mysqli_error($con)` instead. 2. The query is still wide open to [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com) attacks. You might want to mention this in your answer.

Comment: 1 more point: if a variable only used once (e.g. `$host`), what's the point of creating it? wasting resources.

Comment: @JakeGould I sure hope you're not doing all this (great) work for nothing. OP hasn't accepted your answer (yet).

Comment: Exactly @JakeGould Say... isn't that one of FORD's slogans? lol

Answer (score 0):

quality of code decoration help to see errors quicker.
try:

```
INSERT INTO `orderbank` (
    `firstname`,
    `lastname`,
    `email`,
    `adress`,
    `mobilephone`,
    `postalcode`,
    `city`,
    `homephone`,
    `deliveryinfo`,
    `cost`,
    `status`) 
VALUES (
    '$firstname',
    '$lastname',
    '$email',
    '$adress',
    '$mobilephone',
    '$postalcode',
    '$city',
    '$homephone',
    '$deliveryinfo',
    '$totalprice',
    '$status')"
```

Comment: I'm guessing that fields like firstname will need to be quoted in SQL, so this is likely to fail.

Comment: true. i usually use those everywhere.

Comment: I mean around the variables in the `VALUES` clause. What do you think will happen when a string like "Anna Sue" is put in `$firstname`?

Comment: oh crap, you are right again!

Comment: Forget about the whole quoting thing — use prepared statements and be done with it. It's so *much* easier. Not to mention secure.

Comment: @AmalMurali I was about to write the very same thing under OP's question lol Mostly the "and be done with it" bit ;-)

Comment: @JakeGould: even someone with only a basic programming experience should be able to figure out how to do prepared statements. And if they can't, then it's a good time to learn how to do more advanced stuff. People shouldn't be coddled.

Answer (score 0):

Better solution would the use of prepared statements and bind parameters.

Why? Here are some of the reasons:

- SQL Injection will not happen.
- There won't be any weird SQL errors like "*column not allowed here*" in `INSERT`.
- Performance will be better if you use prepared statement.
- Code will be much more cleaner.

Here is sample code:

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'world');

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO Country (ID, Name) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('is', $id, $name);

    $id = 1;
    $name = "USA";

    $stmt->execute();

    printf("%d Row inserted.\n", $stmt->affected_rows);

    $stmt->close();

    $mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: How about an actual code example?

Comment: *this is not an answer* you just avoid the issue, not solving it. And prepared statement has worse performance in some cases.

Comment: No syntax errors are `weird SQL errors`, its us who don't understand how to use the language properly

Comment: "*Performance will be better if you use prepared statement.*" — This isn't strictly true, either.

Comment: @Raptor: what? This is the actual *right* way to do a query and also detect and handle errors. Of course, if there's a syntax error, it'll still have to be dealt with separately, but at least you also don't have injection vulnerabilities and syntax errors due to interpolating unsanitized variables into strings.